# DNS issue with Jenkins deployed via helm UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am unable to update Plugins in Jenkins deployed via helms on k8s. Getting "There were errors checking the update sites: UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io"

```
jenkins@k8s-worker1:/$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search jenkins.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local mydomain.org
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5

jenkins@k8s-worker1:/$ cat /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file (host network).
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 k8s-worker1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

jenkins@k8s-worker1:/$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=17.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=10.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=10.2 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.293/12.738/17.569/3.417 ms

jenkins@k8s-worker1:/$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same dns error and I've tried manually configuring DNS servers for the pod. that did not help

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your post what the exact problem is.
Are you suddenly unable to resolve google.com?

Some info is here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/

You basically want to verify that your master server jenkins pod, which probably does that lookup, is able to resolve the name.

The hostfile looks good if the dnsPolicy is Clusterfirst or ClusterfirstWithHostnet.
It depends on your setup and configuration.

More info on troubleshooting:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

You can inject your own DNS config in de deployment or check any VPC-network setup you have.
Good luck and please post if you found the exact issue.